# Is there a way to change desktop screen color with ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a simple Electronjs app and I wanted to change the desktop screen color somehow, but I can't find a way to access the VGA or Monitor settings, so I was wondering is this posible and how?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit. What exactly do you mean by change screen color? Change the background to a solid color? Or just make the entire screen show a solid color (over UI and everything)?

Comment: I want to change the entire screen to show a specific color (yes over the UI and everything)

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a fullscreen browser window and set the background color to your given color using the options to [BrowserWindow](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#class-browserwindow). Just change #ABABAB in the example given.

```
const electron = require('electron');
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

app.on('ready', () => {
const {width, height} = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize

let win = new BrowserWindow({ fullscreen: true, backgroundColor: 
"#ABABAB" })

});
```

If you don't want to make a "fullscreen" window, you can create a window that is the same size as the screen and place that over everything. This will **not** cover the menu bar in OSX, though.

```
const electron = require('electron');
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');


app.on('ready', () => {
const {width, height} = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay().size
console.log(width + "|" + height);
let win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: width,
        height: height,
        x:0, y:0,
        alwaysOnTop: true,
        frame: false,
        resizable: false,
        backgroundColor: "#ABABAB"
})
win.setAlwaysOnTop(true, "screen-saver");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a simple solution to my problem and it's with electron-notify, when the app is ready I set a notification with custom html template with some color on the body and opacity 0.5 and set the notification to be bigger than my screen so I can be sure it will be on the entire screen

```
app.on('ready', () => {
 const maxWidth = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize.width;
 const maxHeigh = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize.heigh;

 // create browser window here and other logic

 const eNotify = require('electron-notify');

 eNotify.setTemplatePath( path-to-template );

 eNotify.setConfig({
  width: maxWidth + 1000,
  height: maxHeight + 1000,
  displayTime: 1000
 });

 eNotify.notify({
  onClickFunc: handleNotificationClick,
  onCloseFunc: handleNotificationClose
 });
})
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't do it directly with Electron. But it's possible to execute other commands that can do this for you. Since you can use npm packages you can also use a package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/wallpaper-cli to set the background image.

Comment: An npm package doesn't magically extend platform capabilities, it's still just app code packaged and distributed in a reusable fashion (be it `.js` code to run on the Electron runtimes or native libraries). If an npm package can do something, you can do the very same thing with self written code as well.